# Вызов контекстного меню по нажатию правой кнопки мыши на ячейку QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

Недавно начал изучать `Python`, `PyQT5`, возник вопрос, каким образом отследить событие нажатия правой кнопкой мыши на ячейку `QTableWidget` для вызова контекстного меню.

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from untitled import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(413, 222)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 391, 181))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Новая строка"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сентябрь "))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Октябрь"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ноябрь"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи `if self.choice_questions.itemAt(point):` вы проверяете нажали ли вы на ячейку или нет, если нажали то выводится тот текст который находится в ячейке 1 иначе ничего не выводит.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.choice_questions = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.choice_questions.setFixedSize(850, 400)
        self.choice_questions.setHeaderLabels(["№", "1", "2"])
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["1", "пример1", "пример2"])
        self.choice_questions.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.choice_questions.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 13))
        self.choice_questions.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.choice_questions.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context)
        layout.addWidget(self.choice_questions)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def context(self, point):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        if self.choice_questions.itemAt(point):
            edit_question = QtWidgets.QAction('Редактировать вопрос', menu)
            edit_question.triggered.connect(lambda: print("Текст в первой ячейке: " + 
                                                          self.choice_questions.itemAt(point).text(1)))
            menu.addAction(edit_question)
        else:
            pass
        menu.exec(self.choice_questions.mapToGlobal(point))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример из [pyqt5][1]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#  -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
###############################################################
# kenwaldek                           MIT-license

# Title: PyQt5 lesson 15              Version: 1.0
# Date: 09-01-17                      Language: python3
# Description: pyqt5 gui and file saving
# pythonprogramming.net from PyQt4 to PyQt5
###############################################################
# do something


import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QFontDialog, QColorDialog, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QProgressBar, QComboBox, QLabel, QStyleFactory, QLineEdit, QInputDialog



class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqt5 Tut')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('pic.png'))

        extractAction = QAction('&Get to the choppah', self)
        extractAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        extractAction.setStatusTip('leave the app')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        openEditor = QAction('&Editor', self)
        openEditor.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        openEditor.setStatusTip('Open Editor')
        openEditor.triggered.connect(self.editor)

        openFile = QAction('&Open File', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.file_open)

        saveFile = QAction('&Save File', self)
        saveFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveFile.setStatusTip('Save File')
        saveFile.triggered.connect(self.file_save)


        self.statusBar()

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveFile)


        editorMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Editor')
        editorMenu.addAction(openEditor)

        extractAction = QAction(QIcon('pic.png'), 'flee the scene', self)
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)
        self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('extraction')
        self.toolBar.addAction(extractAction)

        fontChoice = QAction('Font', self)
        fontChoice.triggered.connect(self.font_choice)
        # self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('Font')
        self.toolBar.addAction(fontChoice)

        cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
        cal.move(500, 200)
        cal.resize(200, 200)

        self.home()

    def editor(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

    def file_open(self):
        # need to make name an tupple otherwise i had an error and app crashed
        name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        print('tot na dialog gelukt')  # for debugging
        file = open(name, 'r')
        print('na het inlezen gelukt') # for debugging
        self.editor()

        with file:
            text = file.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(text)

    def file_save(self):
        name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save File', options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        file = open(name, 'w')
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        file.write(text)
        file.close()

    def color_picker(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        self.styleChoice.setStyleSheet('QWidget{background-color: %s}' % color.name())

    def font_choice(self):
        font, valid = QFontDialog.getFont()
        if valid:
            self.styleChoice.setFont(font)

    def home(self):
        btn = QPushButton('quit', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(0, 100)

        checkBox = QCheckBox('Enlarge window', self)
        # checkBox.toggle()  # if you want to be checked in in the begin
        checkBox.move(0, 50)
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.enlarge_window)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(200, 80, 250, 20)

        self.btn = QPushButton('download', self)
        self.btn.move(200, 120)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.download)

        self.styleChoice = QLabel('Windows', self)
        comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        comboBox.addItem('motif')
        comboBox.addItem('Windows')
        comboBox.addItem('cde')
        comboBox.addItem('Plastique')
        comboBox.addItem('Cleanlooks')
        comboBox.addItem('windowsvista')

        comboBox.move(25, 250)
        self.styleChoice.move(25, 150)
        comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.style_choice)

        color = QColor(0,0,0)
        fontColer = QAction('font bg color', self)
        fontColer.triggered.connect(self.color_picker)
        self.toolBar.addAction(fontColer)

        self.show()

    def style_choice(self, text):
        self.styleChoice.setText(text)
        QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create(text))

    def download(self):
        self.completed = 0

        while self.completed < 100:
            self.completed += 0.0001
            self.progress.setValue(self.completed)

    def enlarge_window(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 600)
        else:
            self.setGeometry(50, 50 , 500, 300)

    def close_application(self):

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('quit application')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":  # had to add this otherwise app crashed

    def run():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        Gui = window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё получилось!!!